# Splitting CSV and saving to Object

Tags: c#, csv, object

I'm trying to read a CSV file and save the data into an object to be imported to a database. The CSV file holds the follow information:

```
Gas Sensor,GS-NO-001,2
Gas Sensor,GS-O2-002,2
Vig,VG-LR-001-FG-003,1
```

I read the file with this:

```
public static void CSVReader()
{
    var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("C:\\PO-02.csv"));
    reader.ReadLine();
    int counter = 0;
    string line;
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\PO-02.csv");
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        counter++;
    }
    file.Close();
}
```

But I can't get a `.Split(',')` to work with this reading method to actually split up the data. I have tried to make a `string[]` to hold data, as well as using `.Split(',')` on the `ReadLine()`.

I would also like to enter the information into an object

```
public class files
    {
        public string product_name { get; set; }
        public string part_number { get; set; }
        public string quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

My question is how can I split the data and save it to an object?

Comment: What happens when you use Split()?

Comment: @BenjaminDrolet get an output of 'System.String[]'. But I don't know if it just messes up the output and is splitting properly or not

Comment: You “can't get `.Split(',')` to work” because it [cannot work](http://www.secretgeek.net/csv_trouble). CSV allows quoting and escaping characters and `Split` does not do that. There are many already working, tested, debugged parsers ready for you to drop into your project. Use them.

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation would be to use [CsvHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/) or a similar project. It does a lot of things that is required for reading CSV files, like escaping quotes and handling different types of delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but I'm not sure why this wouldn't work for you:

```
public static List<string[]> CSVReader()
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("C:\\PO-02.csv"))
    {
        var csv = new List<string[]>();
        reader.ReadLine();
        int counter = 0;
        string line;
        using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader("C:\\PO-02.csv"))
        {
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                list.Add(line.Split(','))
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return list;
     }
}
```

P.S. Parsing CSV files can be a little more complicated than simply splitting on a comma. If you want to read up on all the rules for your own parser, Wikipedia has a [pretty good list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules) of them.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following which would also return to you a list of 'files' objects:

```
public static List<files> CSVReader()
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("C:\\PO-02.csv"));
        reader.ReadLine();
        int counter = 0;
        string line;
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\PO-02.csv");

        // Create a list to hold your 'files' objects
        List<files> items = new List<files>();
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            // Add a new 'files' object to your list by passing it the split csv line
            string[] data = line.split(",");
            items.Add(new files(data));
            counter++;
        }
        file.Close();
        return items;
    }
```

This of course assumes you have a constructor for your 'files' class that looks like this:

```
public files(string[] data)
{
    product_name = data[0];
    part_number = data[1];
    quantity = data[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it only by using Linq.

```
var result = File.ReadLines("C:\\PO-02.csv")
                 .Select(line => {
                     var chunk = line.Split(',');
                     return new files
                     {
                         product_name = chunk[0],
                         part_number = chunk[1],
                         quantity = chunk[2]
                     };
                 }).ToList();
```

Comment: You could use `File.ReadLines` instead of reading all text and splitting it at `\n`. Starting with .NET 4.0.

Comment: @Koopakiller: You are right. I added unnecessary overhead. I changed the code.